# iPhone Image Zoom Animation

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

I am writing my first iPhone app. I'm looking for direction on how to best accomplish an image zoom animation. I have a thumbnail sized image on the screen, and want to show a larger sized image overlaid on the view when the user taps on the thumbnail.

I've seen some suggestions for using the core animation framework. I saw another suggestion to use ImageKit. Is ImageKit available on iPhone, or just OSX?

Again, I'm just getting started, and looking for some guidance.

Comment: ImageKit is available on MacOS only

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ImageKit` is not available on iPhoneOS, so you have to use `CoreAnimation` from these choices.

Or you could try to use [UIView animation blocks](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/WindowsandViews/WindowsandViews.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH8-SW11), which is much simpler (but limited compared with CA).